# Group nodes in one publication

Tags: 7, nodes

I'm looking for solution to group multiple nodes in to one publication. Idea here is to publish nodes as once like in online magazine as publication.

I did found [EPublish](https://www.drupal.org/project/epublish) module but it is not ported to D7 and not maintained anymore.

What kind of ways there is to control multiple nodes and their publish time/date and also possiblity to treat them as one publication so maintaining and making new publication is simple?

I know this is a bit broad question but I'm searching for the right way to go with this since I dont have clear idea how to implement publication functionality.

Comment: Can't you achieve this with Rules + Node reference field? You can have "Publication" node that will reference regular pages, and once that node is published Rules can fetch all referenced nodes and update them as well.

Comment: Book module bundled with Core?